# Issue with AudioRecord behaviour

Tags: android, memory-leaks, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I'm struggling to get things right using AudioRecord.

Basically what I'm trying to do is seldomly record from the audio on my Android device.
I don't have to get a continuous stream of bytes from the audio source, but I have to feed a buffer every 5 minutes or so.

The problem is that the memory used by my program increases everytime I'm recording (I used the DDMS to investigate my memory issue). I reduced my code to the following lines to better understand the issue.

```
    buffersizebytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPPERSEC,
            channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
    tabbAudioBuffer = new byte[buffersizebytes];

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
            android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPPERSEC,
            channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, buffersizebytes);

    int i=1000;
    while(i-->0) {  
        audioRecord.startRecording();
        audioRecord.stop();
    }

    audioRecord.release();
    audioRecord = null;
```

Please let me know if you can help me with my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Why u are starting and stopping audioRecord object 1000 times, why ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and am really interested if you can dig something out.
I guess the idea of the code is to show the increase of memory when you call `startRecording()`, then do something, then `stop()`... multiple times.